# Representing clustered points above 80,000 in map using ArcGIS 10.2.1 in such a way that their labels and points themselves are clearly visible?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, labeling, cartography, representation, aggregate-points

I have places of Pakistan which are 85949 in number, I want to display them on a static map in such a way that points and their labels are readable and they don't overlap or map doesn't look messy. I have tried Disperse tool, Aggregate tool and have also tried the following method:

1. Firstly created buffer on points by the radius of 5 km. Dissolve Type was ALL
2. Exploded the buffers with Multipart to Singlepart
3. Used a Spatial Join through Join Data to join the original points to the exploded buffers, giving you buffers with a point count.

I thought this would create polygons with count of places which it did but, around 8000 points came in one polygon which is again difficult to represent with labels in a map.
I am attaching picture as reference.

Comment: 10.2 might be too old for all the neat aggregation tools I've seen in the UI in the past  6-7 years. Label visibility is still a topic of research, and depends greatly on the ground/figure relationship (you didn't include the referenced picture).

Comment: To compliment @Vince you need to show the extent of what you are trying to label, a district or the entire country of Pakistan? Nearly 86K labels on any map is going to be unreadable. You might want to put a scale dependency on your labels, as you zoom in/out labels turn on/off. But this would be for a map to be viewed in a GIS system and not printed out.